# Junit not failing even if exception is thrown?

Tags: java, junit

I don't understand,

I am doing some BigDecimal calculation, and at some point an exception is thrown (because a rounding mode is needed).
I have been able to spot this because I have been debugging the tests.

**BUT if I run the test, they do not fail!!!** (I am not catching the exception, they should fail!)

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import model.classes.ShoppingItem;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class FooTetst

@Test
public void test()  {

    BigDecimal foo= new BigDecimal("0.000001");

    foo.multiply(new BigDecimal("1")).setScale(4);//Exception thrown

    assertTrue(true);//test never gets here but it does not fail!
    }

    }
```

---

I would like to know if there is a safe way to run the tests: ie fail if an exception is thrown...

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DaveNewton nope Dave

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a **specific problem** with the **complete error message and/or stacktrace** and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please review [How to ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is a polite way of saying you have to invest a minimum amount of effort that is not evident here to get someone to spend some effort giving you a useful answer.

Comment: Please post your test unit code

Comment: Running the exact test you posted results in a failing test for me.

Comment: yes, you are right @RogerLindsjö, better so, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, and check if throw the exception

```
 public class JunitTest2 {

            @Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class)  
            public void checkException() {  
              you code 
            }  

        }
```

Comment: thanks a lot Ahil, I understand I can do this, but I would like to understand if I can avoid the strange situation I am in, because I need the test to fail if an exception is thrown